# How to disable the Samsung Sidebar?

Tags: java, android

[Sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeBFO.jpg)

In order to access the sidebar, the user has the press the long back button.

I was wondering if there are anyways to prevent the user from accessing the Sidebar?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you mean on the "sidebar"? can you attach screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

The special behaviour of the back button is a Samsung OS specific, meaning they added it to their flavour of Android.

Thus, i fail to see how you can disable it from user code.

One option (although it would be a bit obtrusive) is to disable the back action completely by overriding and see if it stops Samsungs OS from picking up on the button (probably not as it would be OS level call).

This could be done like this:

```
@Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
}
```

Remember, like i said, this is a bit intrusive, as you alter the behaviour of a common usage method. And it is also not guaranteed to stop Samsung devices to bring up the menu, as that is likely a call on OS not user-level.